# Calculating column width within a square to control item distance on the circumference of a circle

Tags: algorithm

I'm struggling to articulate this question so I'll do my best and clean it up as my understand improves.

Let's say we have a square that is divided up into vertical segments via lines. Inside our square we also have a circle that fits perfectly.

Inside each vertical segment I place an item that sits directly over the circumference of the circle.

Is there an algorithm that defines what width each segment must be in order that the items within each segment, whilst sitting on the circumference of the circle, are also of equal distance from one another?

Here's my amazing whiteboard sketch of the scenario:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that you had something like this in mind.

[image]

Here's the Python that generated the image above, using the mathematics described below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import math
import sys


def layout(n):
    assert isinstance(n, int)
    assert n >= 1
    divisions = [0.0] * (n + 1)
    divisions[0] = -1.0
    divisions[n] = 1.0
    for i in range(1, (n + 1) // 2):
        box = -math.cos(i / (n + 1) * math.pi)
        divisions[i] = 2.0 * box - divisions[i - 1]
        divisions[n - i] = -divisions[i]
    return divisions


def quality(divisions):
    n = len(divisions) - 1
    boxes = [0.5 * (divisions[i] + divisions[i + 1]) for i in range(n)]
    angles = [math.asin(box) for box in boxes]
    differences = [angles[i] - angles[i + 1] for i in range(n - 1)]
    return max(differences) - min(differences)


def eps(divisions):
    n = len(divisions) - 1
    print('%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0')
    print('%%BoundingBox: 0 0 216 216')
    print('0.008 setlinewidth')
    print('108 108 translate')
    print('90 90 scale')
    print('newpath 1 1 moveto -1 1 lineto -1 -1 lineto 1 -1 lineto closepath stroke')
    print('newpath 0 0 1 0 360 arc closepath stroke')
    for i in range(n):
        x = 0.5 * (divisions[i] + divisions[i + 1])
        print('newpath {} {} moveto 0.05 0.05 rmoveto -0.1 0 rlineto 0 -0.1 rlineto 0.1 0 rlineto 0 0.1 closepath fill'.format(x, math.sqrt(1 - x ** 2)))
    print('[0.016 0.016] 0 setdash')
    for i in range(1, n):
        print('newpath {} 1 moveto 0 -2 rlineto stroke'.format(divisions[i]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    eps(layout(11))
    for m in range(2, 12):
        print(quality(layout(m)), file=sys.stderr)
```

Assume standard mathematical coordinates like so.

```
         +y
          ^
          |
   (-1,1) | (1,1)
         +-+
-x <-----|O|-----> +x
         +-+
  (-1,-1) | (1,-1)
          |
          v
         -y
```

Since the boxes should have equidistant centers lying on the circle, it follows that those centers should have angles at regular intervals. The point at angle `θ` (in radians) is `(cos θ, sin θ)`. The top of the circle is `θ = π/2`, so the angles in your example might be (left to right) `11π/12, 3π/4, 7π/12, 5π/12, π/4, π/12` (interval is `-π/6`).

Let the x-coordinates of these points be `b(1) ≤ b(2) ≤ ... ≤ b(n)` (`b` for box). We want to find divider positions `d(1) ≤ d(2) ≤ ... ≤ d(n-1)` such that each box is centered at the midpoint of the two adjacent dividers, i.e.,

```
       d(0) + d(1)
b(1) = -----------
            2

       d(1) + d(2)
b(2) = -----------
            2

...

       d(n-1) + d(n)
b(n) = ------------- ,
             2
```

where `d(0) = -1` and `d(n) = 1` are the edges of the box.

This is a system of `n` equations in `n-1` variables. For general values of `b(i)`, this system would not have a solution. Fortunately, it's possible to exhibit a particular choice of `b(i)` that can be achieved.

```
b(i) = -cos((i/(n+1)) pi)
```

Comment: David, this is a magnificent answer. Thanks for taking the time to put this together along with the implementation. Much appreciated. It's going to take me a few reads to understand what's going on so I'll spend some time with it before I start asking any questions. Thanks again!